# Permutations of a list containing the same element several times

Tags: haskell, combinations, permutation

I have to write a function that takes two numbers and does this:

```
placeOneBlock 1 5
["feeee", "efeee", "eefee", "eeefe", "eeeef"]
```

So it makes every permutation of an m long list with n * "f"-s and m-n * "e"-s. If n > 1 than the "f"-s should stay in one group like so:

```
placeOneBlock 3 10
["fffeeeeeee", "efffeeeeee", "eefffeeeee", "eeefffeeee", "eeeefffeee", "eeeeefffee", "eeeeeefffe", "eeeeeeefff"]
```

I wrote this function:

```
placeOneBlock n m = permutations (replicate n 'f' ++ replicate (m-n) 'e')
```

But this views the "e"-s as unique elements so makes much more permutations than I need and also doesn't work if n > 1. How can I do this?

Comment: Thinking of this as a "permutation" of the list is making things harder for you, because you don't want to permute anything. Instead, try thinking of it as a function that makes a non-deterministic *choice*, choosing one of N places within the stream of Es to place a block of Fs. Nondeterminism is well-modeled by a list of possible results, so you will do well to write a recursive function consuming the list and producing a list as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Each possible combination has some E's, some F's, and some E's, in that order. I.e., it is of this form

```
replicate k 'e' ++ replicate n 'f' ++ replicate (m-n-k) 'e'
```

Now, make `k` range over the "right" interval, using a list comprehension, and you're done.

Comment: But how do I make k range over m-n in haskell?

Comment: "using a list comprehension"

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, this is not a permutation problem at all. Rather, you want to walk through the input stream, choosing exactly one place to insert the block of interloping characters. If the input stream is empty, you have no choice, and must insert the block at the end. Otherwise, you may choose to insert the block at the current location, or otherwise to insert it later, in which case you include one more item from the primary stream before the block.

```
block :: a -> a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]
block stream interloper width = go
  where go 0 = [replicate width interloper]
        go n = (replicate width interloper ++ replicate n stream)
               : ((stream :) <$> go (n - 1))

placeOneBlock :: Int -> Int -> [String]
placeOneBlock = block 'e' 'f'
```

This solution is a bit more complicated than chi's answer, which proposes to write something like `replicate x 'e' ++ replicate y 'f' ++ replicate z 'e'` for all appropriate choices of x/y/z. An upside of my solution is it is much simpler to modify to handle multiple block objects rather than just one, or some other rule that indicates where a block is legal. But if you don't anticipate any of this changing, chi's solution sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has got nothing to do with permutations. It's a simple split and insert at all positions job. You may implement as follows;

```
allSplits :: Int -> Int -> [String]
allSplits 0 m = [replicate m 'e']
allSplits n m | n >= m    = [fs]
              | otherwise = (fs ++ replicate (m-n) 'e') : map ('e':) (allSplits n (m-1))
                where fs  = replicate n 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
placeOneBlock 0 m = [replicate m 'e']
placeOneBlock n m | n == m    = [fs] 
 | n > m = []
 | otherwise = (fs ++ replicate (m-n) 'e') : map ('e':) (placeOneBlock n (m-1))
            where fs  = replicate n 'f'
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to add why this works and explain the changes you made?